# Routing Issue With Areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-areas

I'm having an issue with routing and areas as the title says. I have ana areas section in my project that just has one area in it. It has a Policy controller in there. Outside in the project there is a controller's folder with a LoginController.

When I try to got to the URL "BoB/Login/ChangeSection" (BoB is project name, Login is controller, ChangeSection is action) it gets sent to "BoB/Policy/Login". This means the Area registration inside the Policy area is grabbing the request and putting the Policy prefix in front when it shouldn't be.

Here is my project RouteConfig

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "BoBHome", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new string[] { "BoB.Controllers" }
            );
```

and here is the Area registration

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {  
        context.MapRoute(
            name: "BoBPolicy_default",
            url: "Policy/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new string[] { "BoB.Areas.BoBPolicy.Controllers" }
        );
    }
```

I was under the impression the namespaces would keep this from happening, but it obviously is not. Any help is appreciated.

Some additional info:

This comes from another project that is not MVC so the Redirect looks like this:

```
Response.Redirect("/BoB/BoBLogin/ChangeSection?controller=PolicyOverview");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is similar to [non area route issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5695797/mvc-areas-non-area-route-resolves-to-area?rq=1), which requires usage of area parameter to prevent area URL prefix inserted when using default route:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{  
    // set area parameter with area name
    context.MapRoute(
        name: "BoBPolicy_default",
        url: "Policy/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        // add area parameter here
        defaults: new { area = "Policy", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        namespaces: new string[] { "BoB.Areas.BoBPolicy.Controllers" }
    );
}
```

NB: Since area route registration always placed on top of default route (read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12293966/6378815) for reasons behind it), it is possible to have routing engine incorrectly picking up default route request into area route when area route constraint(s) not specified.

Related:

[MVC5 Routing Go to specific Areas view when root url of site is entered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30322218/mvc5-routing-go-to-specific-areas-view-when-root-url-of-site-is-entered)